# Show that $⟨f,g⟩$ is a symmetric nondegenerate bilinear form on $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that $⟨f,g⟩$ is a symmetric nondegenerate bilinear form on $V$.

$V$ is simply the vector space of functions of continuous real-valued functions on the interval [0,1] ($f,g \in V$). And  $⟨f,g⟩$ is defined as:

$⟨f,g⟩:= \int_{0}^1f(x)g(x)dx$

So my attempt goes as follows:

Since $f$ and $g$ are both continuous and real valued functions, then $\int_{0}^1f(x)g(x)dx$
 = $\int_{0}^1g(x)f(x)dx$ and therefore $⟨f,g⟩ = ⟨g,f⟩$.

And, let $f \neq 0$, then one could define $g$ as any constant which would automatically show that $⟨f,g⟩$ is non degenerate.

Is this proof enought to show that $⟨f,g⟩$ is a symmetric nondegenerate bilinear or do I need to do a more rigorous procedure.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: (i) You've shown symmetric. (ii) You've not yet proved bilinear. (iii) Your proof of non-degenerate is no good: the proof uses non-trivial properties of continuous functions.

Comment: @ancientmathematician could I use $g(x)=1/f(x)$ since $f(x)\neq 0$? That way $⟨f,g⟩$ would be different from zero?

Comment: Although $f\not=0$, there may be points in the interval so that $x\mapsto 1/f(x)$ might not be defined.

Comment: I think this is effectively the same question, it gives a reference to the theorem needed for the "difficult" property: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588949/inner-product-with-integration